# Extract column from table with empty and non empty columns with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a table with some server details and I need to extract their status

```
Server            Server-ID        Hostname         Last Online               Status        
------------     -----------       ---------        --------------            ------
server1                                             2018-Mar-13 21:39:45      RUNNING
server2                                             2018-Mar-13 21:39:35      RUNNING
server3                                             2018-Mar-13 21:51:32      RUNNING
server4          XX-YY             ubuntu           2018-Mar-13 21:55:04      RUNNING
server5                                             2018-Mar-13 21:52:48      RUNNING
server6                                             2018-Mar-13 21:43:58      RUNNING
```

Output required:

```
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
```

From the above table I need to get the Status of all the servers. The columns Server-ID and Hostname can be empty or have a couple of entries. What is the simplest way I can do this?
I tried a couple of awk commands but didnt find a complete solution

Comment: `tried a couple of awk commands` please add those to question.. else it'd come across as asking for free coding service which isn't a fit for this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `awk` will help.

```
awk 'FNR>2{print $NF}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Checking condition `FNR>2` which checks if line number is greater than `2` then only proceed with further commands. `{print $NF}` means to print the last column's value.